# Ubuntu over Kali+Win8 = Ubuntu+Win8

Tags: dual-boot

I have an existing dual boot system
Windows 8 was installed first and then came Kali.
Now when I'm done with Kali I want to replace it with Ubuntu.

How would you suggest I do this so that from

```
Win8 + Kali
```

I will end up with

```
Win8 + Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to go about it.

If you are happy with the partition layout, etc. then simply install Ubuntu to the partition(s) that Kali is using, formatting during the setup process. Ubuntu will write a new version of grub that references itself and Windows, and that is it.

If you aren't happy with the partition scheme that Kali is using, boot with the Ubuntu CD/DVD and delete all the Linux partitions, then use your Windows disk to fix the Windows boot loader.  Now you have a stand alone Windows machine, wiht unpartitioned space on the disk.  Boot again with the Ubuntu installer, and install it to the free space using whatever partitioning scheme you like.

Comment: At the moment I am still using Kali but once I'm done with it I'll try one of your options. I've already downloaded Ubuntu yesterday just a matter of time switching to it. Thank you for the information by the way saves me a lot of time and worries.

Comment: Another option which I'd recommend over dual boot would be to use a good desktop OS and then run all the other stuff in virtualbox or similar virtualization software.  Makes experimenting with stuff soooo easy, and I always have my preferred files, mails, etc. "native"